# Here API - These credentials do not authorize access - Some Requests

Tags: here-api

Im getting some 403 errors in some HERE position requests. Looks like that the servers are not synchronized.

My Account was created 2 weeks ago.

```
{"error":{"code":403,"description":"These credentials do not authorize access. Please contact your customer representative or submit a request here https://developer.here.com/contact-us to upgrade your account. You can also get valid credentials by registering for a free trial license on https://developer.here.com.","message":"Forbidden"}}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What URL were you trying to reach.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your support. We are using the https://pos.cit.api.here.com/positioning/v1/locate?app_id=xxxxxx&app_code=xxxxx

Comment: Does this happen only for the Positioning API or also for other APIs? Also, what does "some errors" mean? Does it consistently return or 403 or just sometimes?

Comment: Hi, We are using only positioning API and the error happens only sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

First, generate [apiKey](https://developer.here.com/documentation/identity-access-management/dev_guide/topics/plat-using-apikeys.html) and [bearer token](https://developer.here.com/documentation/identity-access-management/dev_guide/topics/plat-token.html) in your [here account](https://platform.here.com/admin/apps). For the apiKey go to your profile, create a new app and then you can generate it under Credentials -> API Keys.

For the bearer token, you first need to create oauth tokens (under Credentials -> OAuth), download the `credentials.properties` file, then use their CLI to generate the bearer token. Before you can use the CLI, you need to [install it](https://developer.here.com/documentation/open-location-platform-cli/user_guide/topics/get-started.html) and then [set it up](https://developer.here.com/documentation/open-location-platform-cli/user_guide/topics/configuration.html#credentials-setup).

I'm on a mac, so for me this installed it:

```
$ brew install heremaps/olp-cli/olp
```

Follow instructions on their page for whatever OS you have. Now you are ready to generate the bearer token. Make sure you are in the same directory where you downloaded the `credentials.properties` file earlier:

```
$ olp credentials import default credentials.properties
```

Generate the token:

```
$ olp api token get
```

Now you have everything to do a call to their API (replace `HERE_API_URL` with the one you want. They have many different ones for various use-cases):

```
GET 
https://{HERE_API_URL}?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY} -H 'Authorization: Bearer {YOUR_TOKEN}'
```

Note: Do not use app_code and app_id. These have been [deprecated](https://developer.here.com/documentation/identity-access-management/dev_guide/topics/dev-appcode.html).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I had only one API key created. Once I created a second API key, the issue went away.

Make sure you have two API keys generated, even if you only use one. The documentation [suggests](https://developer.here.com/documentation/identity-access-management/dev_guide/topics/plat-using-apikeys.html#step-2-get-an-api-key) setting two keys but it never mentions it's required.

Answer (score 0):

True.
Once created the second API Key, you can delete the first one and remain with just one.